# iOS: why can not I programmatically set frame for the button?

Tags: ios, button, frame

Here is a strange thing, but I couldn't figure it out. I can not programmatically set frame for the button.

I have a button with IBOutlet as beyondViewButton and I control-dragged it from view to the ViewController.m file @interface and @end section, then @synthesized it.

in the viewDidLoad method, I added this:

```
   //x = x + widthToUse * 0.25;
   //y += h + 50;
   x = 50; //either hard code x value or set it mathematically, not working
   y = 300;
   w = 200;
   h = 60;
   //[beyondViewButton setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, w, h)]; //not working 
   beyondViewButton.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h); //not working
   //[beyondViewButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bgImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; //this line actually works
   //[beyondViewButton setTitle:@"iCool!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [beyondViewButton setTitle:@"iShit!" forState:UIControlStateNormal]; //change from iCool to iShit, I can see change
   //[self.view addSubview:beyondViewButton]; //either adding this line or not, both work
```

Why I can not set up the frame?

One thing, I don't know if relevant, is that this button was set up in the "selection view" which comes from Navigation controller and goes to next view/scene. When this button is clicked, app moves from the "selection view" to the next view --- this was implemented via storyboard. I have not mastered storyboard well yet and have lots of uncertainty about it.

Can anyone shed some lights on this? Thanks!!

More diagnosis info:
I checked the button.description before and after I set frame code:

```
     2012[25830:12503] beyond button <UIRoundedRectButton: 0x8821cd0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); opaque = NO; autoresize = TM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x8821da0>>
```

that's before and following is after. Interestingly, the frame values are not what I set, as in code shown here, I have x=50, y=300, w=200, h=60, while NSLog description gives out x=190, y=345, w=110, h=94, which is around the position I saw in run time. It's the values I set in storyboard.

```
     2012[25830:12503] beyond button <UIRoundedRectButton: 0x8821cd0; frame = (190 345; 110 94); opaque = NO; autoresize = TM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x8821da0>>
```

If I commented out set frame lines of the code, when I check button description, before and after the button settings, I got 0,0,0,0 as button frame --- although I see buttons in the bottom half of the view. In another word, the line of setting frame does work SOME WAY, but not the way I wanted. It just takes storyboard values, but not those I set by x,y,w,h.

Comment: I just checked the button description and got this:   beyond button <UIRoundedRectButton: 0x906f230; frame = (0 0; 0 0); opaque = NO; autoresize = TM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x906f300>>    Interestingly, the frame is 0,0,0,0, while I saw the button at the bottom half of my view --- I dragged the button to there in storyboard. How come?

Comment: Got what? Don't make us guess.

Comment: I hit "Enter" and the comment got posted. Looks like only one line comment is allowed. I'm using Safari, not sure if it's because of this.

Comment: Comments can only be one line - we've all been caught by that. :)  Where did you "check the button"? Was it right after you set the frame in the code above? Did you check the `beyondViewButton` ivar or by any chance was it `_beyondViewButton`?

Comment: #@interface ViewController ()
#@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *beyondViewButton;

#@end

#@implementation ViewController {
}
#@synthesize beyondViewButton;
Then in viewDidLoad, right before I set frame for the button, I checked the button description. and I also checked all subviews of the view, and I got the same button description. don't know how to check iVar.  Maddy, thanks, you're so nice and responsive!  Stackoverflow does not allow more than one @, so i have to commented it out.

Comment: Put code in back ticks (\`). Try changing your code to `self.beyondViewButton.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,w,h);`.

Comment: no luck with self.beyondViewButton.frame either. I wonder if there's any "property" that I "locked" or "disabled" in storyboard accidentally so that I could not modify it programmatically. Is there such thing?

Comment: I updated a bit more info. Looks like I my setFrame code did change the frame, but the button is not set to what I have in the code, but set to what I have in storyboard. Any trick did I miss?

Comment: @Tony Xu Though I see a proper (sort of) autoresize mask for the button I'd still recommend to try to assign frame value in `viewWillAppear:` since controller's view is not being adjusted by the parent controller in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: @hoha, Thanks for your input too. I got no change either in viewWillAppear method.

Comment: @Tony Xu I see. This looks really weird to me, especially the zero-frame. Try to create this button programmatically (temporary), add some generic view as a button's sibling too and investigate if it reacts correctly to frame changes.

Comment: @hoha, tried your suggestion. I'm able to programmatically add a button the view with x,y,w,h (y+=50 to move it a little bit lower). Funny thing is that I can change background image and color for the beyondViewButton, but not the frame. What else properties I could try to see if I cannot programmatically change for the button? Maybe I can use this to diagnose what went wrong.                       I'll wait if anyone can solve the problem for me, otherwise I just have to go for all programmatically created buttons.

Comment: @Tony Xu Is your storybord using new auto layout features? If you do - try to turn it off for the button. I'm not familiar with the feature so it's a blind shot but I don't know what else to suspect.

Comment: @hoha, YES!!!! that was it. I noticed this option was checked, but I didn't change it BECAUSE I saw it's checked in all of other projects and I was able to move buttons in those projects. Don't know why this one is different. Please move your comments to answer, I'll accept it. Thanks again!

Comment: thanks both Maddy and Hoha for your help and input!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is your storybord using new auto layout features? If it does - try to turn it off for the button. I'm not familiar with the feature so it's a blind shot but I don't know what else to suspect.

Answer (score 13):

If you have Auto-layout enabled on interface builder, you can also remove the button from view, size it, and then re-add it. Kind of ghetto, but it works.

Something similar to this...

```
[self.myButton removeFromSuperview];
[self.myButton setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];
[self.myButton sizeToFit];
[self.myView addSubview:self.myButton];
```

Comment: Worked for me. No need for sizeToFit as I was manually sizing the frame with CGRectMake...

Answer (score 0):

When working with button that was added using **Autolayout**, I was having size issues.

Adding below line worked well for me,

```
self.button.sizeToFit()
self.button.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)
```

Note: I was doing rotation transform animation of button as well.